# How to check if any user is in a specific channel (discord c#)?

Tags: c#, discord

This is my current code, I want it that it checks if any user is in a specific (pre-determined) voice channel?

```
[Command("moveme")]
        public async Task Moveme()
        {

            var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
            await ReplyAsync("<@" + Context.Message.Author.Id + ">");
            await user.ModifyAsync(x => { x.ChannelId = 936628852996833329; });

        }
```

Thanks beforehand